# How to graph throughput

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, dataset

**UPDATE 2:** maybe a simple way to state it: for web application performance data consisting on:

**start timestamp** | **end timestamp** | **response time**

I'd like to compute a non-aggregated data set consisting of:

**event (=any start or end) time stamp** | **time delta since last event** | **active requests since last event**

Latest column should be divided by time delta to get a throughput (req/s), but that'll be easy enough.

Does this kind of processing have a name?

My goal is to find some easy way to graph it, and just see if it makes any sense.

---

**UPDATE 3:** here is the graph I created. New rephrasing of my original question: does this beast have a name? Or: is there a simple way to do this?
[image: throughput graph]
This is basically how I did it: (R)

```
    startEvents <- data.frame(eventTime  = currentData$relStart)
endEvents <- data.frame(eventTime  = currentData$relEnd)
    startEvents$relCount = 1
endEvents$relCount = -1
    events <- rbind(startEvents, endEvents)
    groupedEvents <- aggregate(relCount ~ eventTime, events, sum)
    groupedEvents$deltaTime <- groupedEvents$eventTime - shift(groupedEvents$eventTime)
groupedEvents$currentRequestCount <- cumsum(groupedEvents$relCount)
groupedEvents$throughput <- groupedEvents$currentRequestCount / groupedEvents$deltaTime / 1000
```

---

**Original question**

First, let me apologize for only having basic statistical background. I hope my question will be clear enough. Feel free to help me improve it.

For performance tests of a web application, I have measurements of response times. I like the idea of keeping all data (without aggregation), and putting all of this in a scatter plot:

[image: scatter plot]

Now, we also want to have some throughput graphs.

We used to draw lines between the throughput data points, which gave some unusable graphs:

[image: throughput, lines]

The same with dots is somewhat clearer:

[image: throughput, dots]

All of which is obviously plotted from aggregated data (number of sample in each 1000 ms slice)...

The latter chart also shows that aggregated metrics like the 'maximum throughput' (aggregated from previously aggregated data), don't make much sense.

Now, I'd like to find some way to have more useful stuf. Maybe a better metric, directly correlated to the response times data? Something like immediate throughput, even if I know it somehow doesn't make sense.

I have some intuition, good or bad, that it looks like the link between speed and acceleration.

What could I do to get some better insight?

UPDATE: we already have some distribution graph which looks like this:
[image]

Is this somehow what is suggested by some users in the comments section?

Seeing that I can gain some insights by a full scatter plot, without aggregation, I'd want to do the same for throughput.

I think @sheß summarized it well: "the discrete nature of that variable is an issue for [me]".

Throughput isn't really the inverse function: it's the number of concurrent requests at any given time. Maybe my issue is some mismatch between "at any given time" and the aggregation: does it even make sense?

I think I can express what I'd want algorithmically:
- compute start/end times for all requests
- for each start time, compute the number of requests at that time.

Maybe the result won't make any sense, but I'd want to try. In other words: is there a name for some kind of function / method / anything that gives me just this?

Comment: Throughput is requests per second? Can you give somewhat more of an explanation why requests per minute would aggregate out too much important bits? Also what is the point you're trying to make with that plot, i.e. what does "more useful stuff" mean in your context.

Comment: You insist on an insanely high resolution, but then complain that the graph isn't very useful.  Sometimes the best way to understand your data is to throw some of it out. But what are you looking for in these response times anyway? There doesn't seem to be much of a pattern just eyeballing it,  so to find a pattern you're going to have to do more work than just looking at the raw data. Welcome to statistics

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and info. There is some pattern in response times: the first graph already shows interesting stuff that would be left out with aggregation. There seems to be multiple clusters of response times (e.g. you typically get an answer either very fast, in about 2000 ms or about 10000, not between). This somehow means that there are multiple code paths. This wasn't expected and is something we can look into to improve performance. I'd want to have something similar for throughput (req/s): graphing all data could give some hints.

Comment: I get the impression that you like to look at random noise and spot "interesting" patterns out of it, under the illusion that this is useful.  Much better (more useful), is to start with the question and/or trends that you are really interested in, and then process the data accordingly to see whether such patterns really exist.  You could start by simply plotting the rolling average throughput rate over time, and maybe look at how the variance (standard deviation) changes also.  Anything else at this stage is really just "mental masturbation" with no real purpose.

Comment: Thanks @Kelvin, but those response time clouds really helped us more than once. This is typical of some cache, virtualisation artifacts, different code paths... From some real life experience in load testing of applications, with hundreds of app tested, I'm sure about the importance of this scatter plot of response times. It does show interesting patterns, and you can see on the first graph (it isn't noise). We did just about what you suggest for throughput. Still, I'm under the impression that less aggregated data could show us some stuff. I'm just lacking the math skills, hence this question

Comment: @ymajoras, no problem, but strong math skills really aren't required if you just want to get a picture of the key patterns. With any (unimodal) distribution, the most important parameter is the mean, followed by the standard deviation (how spread out the data is), and then the skewness (degree of assymmetry) and kurtosis (how long or short the tails are, depending on how far out the most extreme outliers are). So I suggest the first step is to see how your mean and standard deviation change with time and/or any other parameters you think may have an impact.  Anything else is probably noise.

Comment: @Kelvin thanks, but I really fail to see how those parameters could help me in the first graph. It could very well just be some misunderstanding of those params from my part. Still, the interesting thing in the first graph is the distribution. I'm under the impression that, similarly, aggregation gives some insights on the throughput graphs, but also removes interesting stuff. So, my question is: how can I get a throughput graph without any aggregation, which still makes some kind of sense. Maybe it's a dead-end, but I really want to see that for myself :-)

Comment: I don't think I fully get your point, but maybe collapsing time (on x axis) should provide valuable info? Say a histogram of response times that may give you a picture of how response times distribute (e.g. unimodal, bimodal, multimodal). You can play with different bin sizes (intervals of response times) and scales (e.g. log of response time) to try to detect what you are eyeballing in the scatterplot. You can even get an idea of underlying processes (say a fit to some expected theoretical distribution tells you something important or find out you have a "mixture").

Comment: For the throughput, if I understand you correctly, the discrete nature of that variable is an issue for you. I see two options there: (1) you could add [jitter](http://thomasleeper.com/Rcourse/Tutorials/jitter.html) to your plot, this makes "eyeballing" easier, or you could (2) collapse your time axis and end up with a histogram or a density plot (as proposed by #FairMiles).

Equivalently to adding jitter you could have broader horizontal stripes with a varying colour intensity to signify how many points fall into that band. Yet this also makes only sense if you care for variation over time.

Comment: Finally I think it's still a little unclear what you're asking. Are requests dealt with one after the other? Isn't then throughput (requests per unit of time) just the inverse of response-time (units of time over requests). Could you clarify then what you mean with "acceleration"?

Comment: Thanks @sheß and FairMiles, I updated my answer with some details.

Comment: So, if anyone can accurately name the beast in update 3, I guess it'll worth the bounty.

Comment: It's called a hardly-interpretable-scatterplot. If you're interested in the load dynamics, you might just want to estimate the probability density over short time intervals and smooth across quantiles to get a nice and easily interpretable figure. You could add those smoothed curves to your 'beast', it'll become a readable-scatterplot of throughput.

Comment: @dv_bn still, the transformation is quite simple, so I guess it has some kind of name. I'm hoping that finding that would give me some insight, maybe a better or cleaner way to do it. I think we already have enough information for this specific load test. The response time scatter plot along with other similar graphs, and others like response time comparisons under different loads etc. already give us that. We know response times need to be improved for this operation, and there are some heavy code paths. My question is rather generic: making better tools for our load tests in general.

Answer (score 1):

To gain better insight into your data you need to know specifically what information is going to be useful to you. You may want to do one of the following, although by no means is this an exhaustive list:

1. Describe your data
2. Interpolate: guess at values of your variables that are within the observed ranges
3. Extrapolate: predict values of your data that are outside the observed ranges, such as predicting how your variables will change over time or how often can you expect to get values larger than a certain threshold.

Describing data usually has to do with aggregating it to capture it's key characteristics. This is especially important in communicating your results to other people because you can clearly and succinctly characterize the data set. To this end you can use graphics to communicate your results (density plots, histograms, heat maps, scatterplots etc.) or summarize your data with numbers (for example using a measure of central tendency like the mean or median and a measure of variation like the standard deviation or interquartile range).

To interpolate you can often use some kind of ad hoc way of modeling your data. for example you can use smoothed histograms or loess trend lines (for time-series data) to guess at unobserved values within observed ranges. This could be useful if you dropped a time frame, for example if there was a temporary problem in data collection but would like to estimate how many clients had problems during that time.

Finally to extrapolate you need a model of the data generating process. Here you need some assumptions about how the data came to be distributed as it is. For example you could check if your throughput data was "generated" by drawing form a Poisson distribution. If you use a statistical distribution to model your data you can ask all kinds of questions. For example if your data comes from a Poisson distribution the mean of the distribution can be interpreted as the average number of concurrent requests.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't think it's what I want, though. I don't need more data (interpolation etc.). Sorry if it wasn't clear.